# How to match word where count of characters same

Tags: regex

Please help with below

I need match only words where counting of characters same

for example same counting for a b c

abc ///match  1 (abc)

aabbcc match 2(abc)

adabb not mach 2(ab)

ttt    match 0(abc)

Comment: Forgive my suspicion, but it sounds like you're asking because this is a homework assignment. Can you word this a bit better and give us some background. Tell us what you've tried already. etc

Comment: This is the perfect example for a non-regular language that a regular expression can’t solve.

Comment: Indeed: regex-es can't count.

Comment: Regex is probably not a good way to go for this problem. Better to write a quick function that loops over the characters of the string once and counts matches for each of the letters. What language are you using?

Comment: Forgive my curiosity but ... why would you want to do that?

Comment: I tryed this so i get the only words where characters appeared mor then one for example ccabab but not abc..  
grep "^(.+)+\1"
Actualy i thing it can't be solve by regex but maybe someone can do it

Comment: @Brann I'm trying to narrow a list of dictionary words down to a combo of words I have placed down on a board. I thought it would be neat to write a script that will give you possible words to play based on the letters available to you and currently on the board. At the moment, I'm figuring out how to whittle the main dictionary list down based on the tiles that are on the board. Hope that makes sense (I'm using JavaScript)! Looping sounds a little too intense at this stage... IF regEx can help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using regular expressions for this?  Regular expressions are the right tool for some jobs but they are overused where plain old string processing would do the trick, possibly with greater clarity or efficiency.  Here's a sample implemented in Python:

```
def matchCount(inputString, lettersToMatch, count) :
    matches = []

    wordsArray = inputString.split()
    for word in wordsArray:
        letterCounts = {}
        for letter in word:
            if letter in letterCounts:
                letterCounts[letter] += 1
            else:
                letterCounts[letter] = 1

        allCorrect = True
        for letter in lettersToMatch:
            if letter !in letterCounts:
                allCorrect = False
            if letterCounts[letter] != count:
                allCorrect = False

            if !allCorrect:
                break

       if allCorrect:
           matches.append(word)
 return matches
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recursive regular expression.

Below is the Perl code for matching the same number or `0`s and `1`s

```
$regex = qr/0(??{$regex})*1/;
```

NB: *for more backround, please refer to [Recursive Regular Expressions](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/recursive-regular-expressions) on Peteris Krumins's blog.*