# Getting equal number of digits on both sides of a character in a string

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a string

```
$test = 'xyz45sd2-32d34-sd23-456562.abc.com'
```

The objective is to obtain $1 = 23 and $2 = 45 i.e equal number of digits on both sides of the last `-`. Note that the number of digits is variable, and is not necessarily 2.

I have tried the following:

```
$test1 =~ s/.*(\d+)-(\d+).*//;
```

But

- $1 contains 3
- $2 contains 456562

Comment: Why do you want (23, 45) and not (23, 456562)?

Comment: Will they always be two digits, or do you mean that it's a variable number of digits before and after the dash? If it's always two digits, you could just use `s/.*(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*//`

Comment: @GreatBigBore - The number of digits is variable, but i wanted to exact numbers on both sides, 
eg: if Left side of '-' has 5 numbers but right side of '-' has 3 numbers then i need to match 3 numbers

Comment: What do you expect in the case if the right side has lesser digits than the left side? For example in the string `xyz45sd2-32d34-sd23-1d3f5b.abc.com`? Would you expect `3` and `1`?

Comment: @Samveen - yes. because the ending sequence from number 1 has the dot. So i want 3 and 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex

```
if($test1 =~ m/(\S+)-(\S+)-([a-z]*)(\d+)-(\d\d)(\d+).*/)
{
    print $4,"|",$5;
}
```

I assume that u need only the first 2 didgits from 456562

Answer (score 1):

`perl -e '"xyz45sd2-32d34-sd23-456562.abc.com" =~ /(\d{2})-(\d{2})\d*(?=\.)/; print "$1\n$2\n"'`

Answer (score 1):

This other entry confirms that regex does not count:
[How to match word where count of characters same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936292/how-to-match-word-where-count-of-characters-same)

Building upon GreatBigBore's idea, if there's an upper bound to the count, then you could try the or operator |.  This only matches your requirement to find a match; depending on the matched count the match will be in different bins.  Only one case correctly places them in $1 and $2.
    `(\d{3})-(\d{3})|(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{1})-(\d{1})`

However if you concatenate the result captures as $1$3$5 and $2$4$6, you will effectively get the 2 stings you were looking for.

Another idea is to operate iteratively, you could repeat your search on the string by increasing the number until the match fails.  `(\d{1})-(\d{1})` , `(\d{2})-(\d{2})` ...

A binary search comes to mind making it an O{ln(N)}, N being the upper limit for the capture length.

Answer (score 1):

## Theoretical answer

### Short answer:

What you're looking for is not possible using regular expressions.

### Long Answer:

Regular expressions (as their name suggests) are a compact representation of [Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) (`Type-3 grammars` in the [Chomsky Heirarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)).

What you're looking for is not possible using regular expressions as you're trying to write out an expression that maintains some kind of count (some contextual information other than `beginning` and `end`). This kind of behavior cannot be modelled as a **DFA**(actually any Finite Automaton). The informal proof of whether a `language` is `regular` is that there exists a **DFA** that accepts that language. As this kind of contextual information cannot be modeled in a **DFA**, thus by contradiction, you cannot  write a regular expression for your problem.

## Practical Solution

```
my ($lhs,$rhs) = $test =~ /^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-([^-.]+)\S+/;
# Alernatively and faster
my (undef,undef,$lhs,$rhs) = split /-/, $test;

# Rest is common, no matter how $lhs and $rhs is extracted.
my @left = reverse split //, $lhs;
my @right = split //, $rhs;

my $i;
for($i=0; exists($left[$i]) and exists($right[$i]) and $left[$i] =~ /\d/ and $right[$i] =~ /\d/ ; ++$i){}

--$i;
$lhs= join "", reverse @left[0..$i];
$rhs= join "", @right[0..$i];

print $lhs, "\t", $rhs, "\n";
```

**Edit:** It's possible to improve the my solution by using regular expressions to extract the required numeric portions of `$lhs` and `$rhs` instead of `split`, `reverse` and `for`.

Answer (score 0):

as @Samveen said it's technically not possible to do in pure regex

And Like @Samveen solution here's another version

```
#get left and right
my (undef,undef,$left,$right) = split /-/, $test;

#get left numbers
$left =~ s/.*?(\d+)$/$1/;

##get right numbers
$right =~ s/^(\d+).*/$1/;

##get length of both
my $right_length = length $right;
my $left_length = length $left;

if ($right_length > $left_length){

    #make right length as same as left length
    $right =~ s/(\d{$left_length}).*/$1/;

} else {

    #make left length as same as right length
    $left =~ s/.*(\d{$right_length})/$1/;

}

print $left, "\t", $right, "\n";
```